# Can't run auto increment build script

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to run a Run Script Phase in Xcode 11.4 to auto increment my build number.

```
#!/bin/bash
bN=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
bN=$((bN += 1))
bN=$(printf "%d" $bN)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $bN" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

When I build my project I get the following error:

/Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dmbnskuxjhlbmpeciklnrsercgqx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Script-E4D01FDD243BC0E2007311D3.sh: line 5: $(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION): syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)")
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your `Info.plist` file related to the project, find the `Bundle Version` key and instead of `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)` add any integer number, i.e. 1 (it should be starting point for incrementing the build number)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how or when Bundle Version changed since it was working at one point. Thank you again!